# Group by for UNION not working Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, union

I can't find a way to make Group by works in Postgresql, How can i make group by works so each name will be only one , not repeated many times like what i got in this picture?

Here is a code for what i have tried:

```
SELECT em_id , em_type, advisor_name, opened_complaints, in_progress_complaints, pending_complaints, closed_complaints, solved_complaints
FROM
  ((SELECT DISTINCT ON (advisor_id) advisor_id as em_id, employees.type as em_type ,employees.full_name as advisor_name, COUNT(ticket_statuses.status_id) AS opened_complaints, 0 AS in_progress_complaints, 0 AS pending_complaints, 0 AS closed_complaints, 0 AS solved_complaints
    FROM ticket_statuses, employees,statuses WHERE ticket_statuses.advisor_id = employees.id AND employees.type = 'Advisor'
                                          AND ticket_statuses.status_id = statuses.id AND statuses.ticket_status = 'Open'
    GROUP BY em_id, advisor_name, em_type)
   UNION
   (SELECT DISTINCT ON (advisor_id) advisor_id as em_id, employees.type as em_type ,employees.full_name as advisor_name, 0 AS opened_complaints, COUNT(ticket_statuses.status_id) AS in_progress_complaints, 0 AS pending_complaints, 0 AS closed_complaints, 0 AS solved_complaints
    FROM ticket_statuses, employees, statuses WHERE ticket_statuses.advisor_id = employees.id AND employees.type = 'Advisor'
                                          AND ticket_statuses.status_id = statuses.id AND statuses.ticket_status = 'In Progress'
    GROUP BY em_id, advisor_name, em_type)
   UNION
   (SELECT DISTINCT ON (advisor_id) advisor_id as em_id, employees.type as em_type,employees.full_name as advisor_name, 0 AS opened_complaints , 0 AS in_progress_complaints, COUNT(ticket_statuses.status_id)AS pending_complaints, 0 AS closed_complaints, 0 AS solved_complaints
    FROM ticket_statuses, employees, statuses WHERE ticket_statuses.advisor_id = employees.id AND employees.type = 'Advisor'
                                          AND ticket_statuses.status_id = statuses.id AND statuses.ticket_status = 'Pending'
    GROUP BY em_id, advisor_name, em_type)
   UNION
   (SELECT DISTINCT ON (advisor_id) advisor_id AS em_id, employees.type as em_type , employees.full_name as advisor_name, 0 AS opened_complaints , 0 AS in_progress_complaints, 0 AS pending_complaints, COUNT(ticket_statuses.status_id) AS closed_complaints, 0 AS solved_complaints
    FROM ticket_statuses, employees, statuses WHERE ticket_statuses.advisor_id = employees.id AND employees.type = 'Advisor'
                                          AND ticket_statuses.status_id = statuses.id AND statuses.ticket_status = 'Closed'
    GROUP BY em_id, advisor_name, em_type)
   UNION
   (SELECT DISTINCT ON (advisor_id) advisor_id AS em_id, employees.type as em_type ,employees.full_name as advisor_name, 0 AS opened_complaints , 0 AS in_progress_complaints, 0 AS pending_complaints, 0 AS closed_complaints, COUNT(ticket_statuses.status_id) AS solved_complaints
    FROM ticket_statuses, employees, statuses WHERE ticket_statuses.advisor_id = employees.id AND employees.type = 'Advisor'
                                          AND ticket_statuses.status_id = statuses.id AND statuses.ticket_status = 'Solved'
    GROUP BY em_id, advisor_name, em_type)
  ) t
GROUP BY t.em_id, t.advisor_name, t.opened_complaints, t.in_progress_complaints, t.pending_complaints, t.closed_complaints, t.solved_complaints, t.em_type ORDER BY t.em_id, t.advisor_name, t.opened_complaints, t.in_progress_complaints, t.pending_complaints, t.closed_complaints, t.solved_complaints, t.em_type;
```

The result was the following:

[image]

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: how can i make group by works ? i searched alot for it but i cant figure out what is the wrong with my code.

Comment: Your code does  not throw any error, so it is correct. Do you mean you want something different as a result and not what you get?

Comment: I expect to have each name one time not 5 times.

Comment: I imagine you miss some aggregates there (no sum(), count() or similar can be seen in your outer query).  Some example data and the expected results (together with a description how it is supposed to be calculated) are seriously missing from your question.

Comment: i tried count() at the first line but it gave me the same result , also i tried sum() which gives me same number of rows with a value 1 on each column

Comment: You are aware that union removes duplicate rows, right? If you don't want the duplicates eliminated, then use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want a PIVOT type of query. No need to overcomplicate it, something like this will work:

```
SELECT 
    em.id         AS em_id, 
    em.type       AS em_type,
    em.full_name  AS advisor_name, 
    COUNT(CASE st.ticket_status WHEN 'Open'        THEN 1 END) AS opened_complaints,
    COUNT(CASE st.ticket_status WHEN 'In Progress' THEN 1 END) AS in_progress_complaints,
    COUNT(CASE st.ticket_status WHEN 'Pending'     THEN 1 END) AS pending_complaints,
    COUNT(CASE st.ticket_status WHEN 'Closed'      THEN 1 END) AS closed_complaints,
    COUNT(CASE st.ticket_status WHEN 'Solved'      THEN 1 END) AS solved_complaints
FROM 
        ticket_statuses AS ti
   JOIN
        employees AS em
             ON  ti.advisor_id = em.id 
   JOIN
        statuses AS st
             ON  ti.status_id = st.id
WHERE 
    em.type = 'Advisor'
  AND
    st.ticket_status IN ('Open', 'In Progress', 'Pending', 'Closed', 'Solved')
GROUP BY 
    em.id,
    em.type,             -- these 2 lines are not strictly needed
    em.full_name ;       -- in Postgres recent versions
```

---

You could change your old code to get the same results, leaving the internal query untouched. This would aggregate each set of 5 rows per person you get from the internal query into one group. The `MAX()` would ensure that the 0s are discarded and the high values are kept:

```
SELECT 
    em_id, em_type, advisor_name, 
    MAX(t.opened_complaints) AS opened_complaints,
    --- ,                --- the rest of the columns with MAX() as above
FROM
  ---        --- unchanged
  ---        ...
  ---        --- unchanged
  ) t
GROUP BY 
    t.em_id, t.em_type, t.advisor_name ;
```

Comment: Can you come to this chat room? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12648/group-by-for-union-not-working-postgresql